# GIS data for region boundary

Tags: gis

I need GIS data for: region's boundaries(polygon) for all countries with region name encoding in UTF-8. Please help me where can i get?

Answer (score 1):

[GADM database of Global Administrative Areas](http://www.gadm.org/) is one possibility.  Also you may want to ask in [gis.stackexchange.com](https://gis.stackexchange.com/) to find data for GIS.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In case somebody looks for download more of cultural, physical and raster data covering the whole world - you should check out [**naturalearthdata.com**](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/).